# How to subscribe to multiple queues (routing key) to a RabbitMQ server with a same client ID / user /password?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, subscribe

I have a problem and about that the MQTT implementation in RabbitMQ broker is not clear.

Here is the problem:

- I have a client which connects to the RabbitMQ broker with a certain client id CLIENTID1, with credentials etc.
- Then it has to subscribe to several "queues". The idea is to be able to "receive" different kind of messages affected to each queue.
  Actually in RabbitMQ language the client subscribes to multiple routing keys. Note that queues and routing keys
  already exist on RabbitMQ server and bindings already exist before client connects.
  In the example here we will say that routing key names are CLIENTID1 and CLIENTID1EXT. Both are subscribed for QOS1. It's a bit confusing but yes the routing keys have names similar to client IDs. Physically on server side bindings already exists for a queue associated to each routing key.
- But when the SUBSCRIBE message is sent to RabbitMQ, I observe that RabbitMQ creates a new binding with mqtt-subscription-CLIENTID1qos1 queue bound to the CLIENTID1EXT routing key !!
  It seems something is 'hardcoded' in RabbitMQ implementation when a client subscribes with several routing key names inside the SUBSCRIBE payload...

Please advice

I expect that RabbitMQ supports multiple subscribe with same client ID and same MQTT connection.

I don't expect that new bindings are created like that...